# XSLT 2.0: How to determine at least one value exists or does not exist in list?

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

The XSLT and XML shown below generates the following output:

```
<CodeGroupA>Found</CodeGroupA>
<CodeGroupB>Not found</CodeGroupB>
<CodeGroupA>Found</CodeGroupA>
<CodeGroupB>Not found</CodeGroupB>
<CodeGroupA>Not found</CodeGroupA>
<CodeGroupB>Not found</CodeGroupB>
```

I need to generate this output:

```
<CodeGroupA>Found</CodeGroupA>
<CodeGroupB>Not found</CodeGroupB>
```

I attempted a number of different methods using recursion and for-each but I cannot figure it out. Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Here is my XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns:math="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/math"
  xmlns:map="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/map"
  xmlns:array="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/array"
  exclude-result-prefixes="xs math map array"
  version="3.0">

  <!-- input/output configuration -->
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:variable name="CodeGroupA" select="'12', '13'" />
  <xsl:variable name="CodeGroupB" select="'17', '18'" />

  <xsl:template match="/Diagnoses/Diagnosis" >

    <xsl:if test=".[Code=($CodeGroupA)]">
        <CodeGroupA>Found</CodeGroupA>
    </xsl:if>

    <xsl:if test="not(.[Code=($CodeGroupA)])">
        <CodeGroupA>Not found</CodeGroupA>
    </xsl:if>

    <xsl:if test=".[Code=($CodeGroupB)]">
        <CodeGroupB>Found</CodeGroupB>
    </xsl:if>

    <xsl:if test="not(.[Code=($CodeGroupB)])">
        <CodeGroupB>Not found</CodeGroupB>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="text()|@*">
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Here is my input XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Diagnoses>
  <Diagnosis>
    <Code>12</Code>
  </Diagnosis>
  <Diagnosis>
    <Code>13</Code>
  </Diagnosis>
  <Diagnosis>
    <Code>14</Code>
  </Diagnosis>
</Diagnoses>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should really match on the `Diagnoses` element, otherwise you will get something output for each `Diagnosis` which is not really what you want.

But if you do this, you can get the result you want by doing this...

```
<CodeGroupA>
    <xsl:value-of select="if (Diagnosis/Code=$CodeGroupA) then 'Found' else 'Not found'" />
</CodeGroupA>
```

And similarly for `CodeGroupB`.

Of course, you could avoid repeated logic by putting the logic in a function. Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:my="my" version="3.0">

  <!-- input/output configuration -->
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:variable name="CodeGroupA" select="'12', '13'" />
  <xsl:variable name="CodeGroupB" select="'17', '18'" />

  <xsl:template match="/Diagnoses" >

    <CodeGroupA>
        <xsl:value-of select="my:check(Diagnosis/Code, $CodeGroupA)" />
    </CodeGroupA>

    <CodeGroupB>
        <xsl:value-of select="my:check(Diagnosis/Code, $CodeGroupB)" />
    </CodeGroupB>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:function name="my:check">
      <xsl:param name="nodes" />
      <xsl:param name="group" />
      <xsl:value-of select="if ($nodes = $group) then 'Found' else 'Not found'" />
  </xsl:function>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Do I understand it correctly? If the match is Diagnoses I am working on a list of Diagnosis instead of a single Diagnosis. Your answer works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Change the context node for the tests:

```
  <xsl:template match="/Diagnoses" >

    <xsl:if test="Diagnosis/Code = $CodeGroupA">
        <CodeGroupA>Found</CodeGroupA>
    </xsl:if>

    <xsl:if test="not(Diagnosis/Code = $CodeGroupA)">
        <CodeGroupA>Not found</CodeGroupA>
    </xsl:if>

    <xsl:if test="Diagnosis/Code = $CodeGroupB">
        <CodeGroupB>Found</CodeGroupB>
    </xsl:if>

    <xsl:if test="not(Diagnosis/Code = $CodeGroupB)">
        <CodeGroupB>Not found</CodeGroupB>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bdxtq9

Comment: Thanks for the reply and the xsltfiddle data.